# An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used?

Tags: c#, ipv6

Here is the Code

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect("fe80::fc33:41d6:77f4:c8c7", 1000);
```

when i try and connect with this address i get the "An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 link-lical addresses are valid on every link, so you need to tell the system which link to use. That is usually done by appending % and the interface id to the address. Using global addresses is usually easier.

Answer (score -1):

I get this error while uploading a folder on my FTP server:

> an address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Sometimes it uploads it successfully, but other times it fails.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormFtpLibraryExtensionDemo : Form
    {
        public FormFtpLibraryExtensionDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static FTP ftplib = null;
        public void ProgressEvent(System.IO.FileInfo File, long BytesTotal, long FileSize, long TotalBytesDirectorySent, long TotalBytesDirectory, long StartTickCount)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { ProgressEvent(File, BytesTotal, FileSize, TotalBytesDirectorySent, TotalBytesDirectory, StartTickCount); }));
                return;
            }

            TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - StartTickCount);

            labelFilename.Text = "Filename: " + File.FullName;
            labelCurrentSend.Text = "Current: " + (BytesTotal / 1024).ToString() + "/" + (FileSize / 1024).ToString() + " KB";
            labelTotal.Text = "Total: " + (TotalBytesDirectorySent / 1024).ToString() + "/" + (TotalBytesDirectory / 1024).ToString() + " KB";
            labelElapsed.Text = "Elapsed: " + string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", elapsedSpan.Hours, elapsedSpan.Minutes, elapsedSpan.Seconds);

            if (progressBar1.Value != (int)((BytesTotal * 100) / FileSize))
                progressBar1.Value = (int)((BytesTotal * 100) / FileSize);

            if (progressBar2.Value != (int)((TotalBytesDirectorySent * 100) / TotalBytesDirectory))
                progressBar2.Value = (int)((TotalBytesDirectorySent * 100) / TotalBytesDirectory);

            if ((new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - updateTime).TotalMilliseconds > 200) || (TotalBytesDirectorySent == TotalBytesDirectory))
            {
                updateTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

                deltabytes = TotalBytesDirectorySent - deltabytes;
                deltatime = elapsedSpan.Subtract(deltatime);

                if (deltatime.Seconds > 0)
                {
                    labelSpeed.Text = "Speed: " + (deltabytes / deltatime.Seconds / 1024).ToString() + " KB/s";

                    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((TotalBytesDirectory - deltabytes) / (deltabytes / deltatime.Seconds));
                    labelRemaining.Text = "Remaining: " + string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
                }
            }

            if (BytesTotal == FileSize)
            {
                deltabytes = 0;
                deltatime = new TimeSpan(0);
            }
        }

        private long deltabytes = 0;
        private TimeSpan deltatime = new TimeSpan(0);

        private long updateTime = 0;

        private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ftplib = new FTP(textBoxHost.Text, textBoxUsr.Text, textBoxPwd.Text);

                ftplib.Connect();

                new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    ftplib.UploadFolderRecursively(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, ProgressEvent);
                }).Start();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.